# Understanding dplyr piping and summarizing function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for some help understanding piping and summarizing functions using dplyr. I feel like my coding is a bit verbose and could be simplified. So there is a couple of questions in here because I know I'm missing some concepts, but I'm not quite sure where that lack of knowledge is. I've included my full code at the bottom. Thanks in advance as this is a bit larger ask.

1a. From the example data below and using dplyr, is there a way to calculate the games(dates) per team without using an intermediate table?

1b. I've included my original way to calculate n_games which didn't work. Why?

```
set.seed(123)
shot_df_ex <- tibble(Team_Name = sample(LETTERS[1:5],250, replace = TRUE),
                     Date = sample(as.Date(c("2019-08-01",
                                             "2019-09-01",
                                             "2018-08-01",
                                             "2018-09-01",
                                             "2017-08-01",
                                             "2017-09-01")), 
                                   size = 250, replace = TRUE),
                     Type = sample(c("shot","goal"), size = 250, 
                                   replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9,0.1))
)

# count shots per team per game(date)
n_shots_per_game <- shot_df_ex %>% 
  count(Team_Name,Date)

n_shots_per_game

# count games (dates) per team [ISSUES!!!]
# is there a way to do this piping from the shot_df_ex tibble instead of 
#  using an intermediate tibble?

# count number of games using the tibble created above [DOES NOT WORK--WHY?]
n_games <- n_shots_per_game %>% 
  count(Team_Name)

n_games #what is this counting? It should be 6 for each.

# this works, but isn't count() just a quicker way to run
#  group_by() %>% summarise()? 
n_games <- n_shots_per_game %>% 
  group_by(Team_Name) %>% 
  summarise(N_Games=n())

n_games
```

2. Below is my process of creating a summary table. I understand that piping is meant to cut out the creation of some intermediate variables/tables. Where could I combine steps below to create the final table with a minimum number of intermediate steps.

```
# load librarys ------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

# build sample shot data ---------------------------------------
set.seed(123)
shot_df_ex <- tibble(Team_Name = sample(LETTERS[1:5],250, replace = TRUE),
                     Date = sample(as.Date(c("2019-08-01",
                                             "2019-09-01",
                                             "2018-08-01",
                                             "2018-09-01",
                                             "2017-08-01",
                                             "2017-09-01")), 
                                   size = 250, replace = TRUE),
                     Type = sample(c("shot","goal"), size = 250, 
                                   replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9,0.1))
)

# calculate data ----------------------------------------------
# since every row is a shot, the following function counts shots for ea. team
n_shots <- shot_df_ex %>% 
  count(Team_Name) %>% 
  rename(N_Shots = n)

n_shots

# do the same for goals for each team
n_goals <- shot_df_ex %>% 
  filter(Type == "goal") %>% 
  count(Team_Name,sort = T) %>% 
  rename(N_Goals = n) %>% 
  arrange(Team_Name)

n_goals

# count shots per team per game(date)
n_shots_per_game <- shot_df_ex %>% 
  count(Team_Name,Date)

n_shots_per_game

# count games (dates) per team [ISSUES!!!]
# is there a way to do this piping from the shot_df_ex tibble instead of 
#  using an intermediate tibble?

# count number of games using the tibble created above [DOES NOT WORK]
n_games <- n_shots_per_game %>% 
  count(Team_Name)

n_games #what is this counting? It should be 6 for each.

# this works, but isn't count() just a quicker way to run
#  group_by() %>% summarise()? 
n_games <- n_shots_per_game %>% 
  group_by(Team_Name) %>% 
  summarise(N_Games=n())

n_games

# combine data ------------------------------------------------
# combine columns and add average shots per game
shot_table_ex <- n_games %>% 
  left_join(n_shots) %>% 
  left_join(n_goals)

# final table with final average calculations
shot_table_ex <- shot_table_ex %>% 
  mutate(Shots_per_Game = round(N_Shots / N_Games, 1),
         Goals_per_Game = round(N_Goals / N_Games, 1)) %>% 
  arrange(Team_Name)

shot_table_ex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1a, you can just pipe straight from the tibble() function to count(). ie.

```
tibble(Team_Name = sample(LETTERS[1:5],250, replace = TRUE),
       Date = sample(as.Date(c("2019-08-01",
                               "2019-09-01",
                               "2018-08-01",
                               "2018-09-01",
                               "2017-08-01",
                               "2017-09-01")), 
                     size = 250, replace = TRUE),
       Type = sample(c("shot","goal"), size = 250, 
                     replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9,0.1))) %>%
count(Team_Name,Date)
```

In 1b, count() is using your column `n` (ie. the number of shots) as a weighting variable so is summing the total number of shots per team, not the number of rows. It prints a message telling you this:

`` Using `n` as weighting variable i Quiet this message with `wt = n` or count rows with `wt = 1` ``

Using `count(Team_Name, wt=n())` will give the behaviour you want.

**Edit:** part 2

```
shot_table_ex <- tibble(Team_Name = sample(LETTERS[1:5],250, replace = TRUE),
                    Date = sample(as.Date(c("2019-08-01",
                                            "2019-09-01",
                                            "2018-08-01",
                                            "2018-09-01",
                                            "2017-08-01",
                                            "2017-09-01")), 
                                  size = 250, replace = TRUE),
                    Type = sample(c("shot","goal"), size = 250, 
                                  replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9,0.1))) %>%
     group_by(Team_Name) %>%
     summarise(n_shots = n(),
               n_goals = sum(Type == "goal"),
               n_games = n_distinct(Date)) %>%
     mutate(Shots_per_Game = round(n_shots / n_games, 1),
            Goals_per_Game = round(n_goals / n_games, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1a. From the example data below and using dplyr, is there a way to calculate the games(dates) per team without using an intermediate table?

This is how I would do it:

```
shot_df_ex %>% 
  distinct(Team_Name, Date) %>% #Keeps only the cols given and one of each combo
  count(Team_Name)
```

You can also use unique:

```
shot_df_ex %>% 
  group_by(Team_Name) %>%
  summarize(N_Games = length(unique(Date))
```

> 1b. I've included my original way to calculate n_games which didn't
> work. Why?

Your code is working for me. Did you perhaps save over the intermediate table? It's counting the expected 6 per team.

> 2. Below is my process of creating a summary table. I understand that piping is meant to cut out the creation of some intermediate
>    variables/tables. Where could I combine steps below to create the
>    final table with a minimum number of intermediate steps?

```
shot_df_ex %>% 
  group_by(Team_Name) %>% 
  summarize(
    N_Games = length(unique(Date)),
    N_Shots = sum(Type == "shot"),
    N_Goals = sum(Type == "goal")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Shots_per_Game = round(N_Shots / N_Games, 1),
         Goals_per_Game = round(N_Goals / N_Games, 1))
```

You can use multiple summarize steps at a time as long as you don't need to change your grouping. We're taking advantage here (in the `sum` calls) of the interpretation of True as 1 and False as 0. `length` will of course give us the length of the vector produced by `unique`.

> this (count) works, but isn't count() just a quicker way to run  group_by() %>% summarise()?

`count` is just a combination of `group_by(col) %>% tally()` and tally is essentially `summarize(x=n())` so yes. :)

Comment: Thanks! Both were especially helpful as you've identified that I need to better understand summary functions to get the info I need.